# why is soup find all not showing all tags

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the daily temperature data from this page - specifically the min and max daily temp: https://www.wunderground.com/calendar/gb/birmingham/EGBB/date/2020-8

I found the line in the html where the data is located:
[calendar days temperature li tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbHx1.png)
and the rest of the daily temperature can also be found in the other li tags:
[other li tags where temp data is inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1jeh.png)

I'm trying to use beautiful soup to scrape the said data but when I try to use the following code, I am not getting all the li tags from the html, even if they are there when I inspect the html at the website

when I print the resulting temp_cont, there are the other li tags but not the ones that contain the daily data: [result of soup find all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U3JY.png)

I've already tried using other html parser but it didn't work - all other parser output the same data.
I'm looking at other solution like trying to load it using javascript since others suggest that some pages may load dynamically but I don't really understand this.
Hope you can help me with this one.

```
response = get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
temp_cont = soup.find_all('li')
```

EDIT (ADDITIONAL QUESTION):
I tested the solution recommended by @AaronS below and the scraping worked perfectly fine. However, when I try to re-run the script again after few hours, an error of 'Nonetype' was prompted since one of the list element is 'None'.

When I inspected the website again in the network preview of the API, the first element of temperatureMax is now written "null". I don't understand why/how it changed or if there's a workaround so that the scraping works again. See screenshot here: [network preview with null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxx4k.png)

Comment: Do you want to scrap Avg min, max or Forecast min, max?

Comment: the information which you are looking for not present inside HTML, because it comes from API. so you have to use API url to get info or try to use ```selenium``` to grab page content

Comment: @Vin it would be best if I get the whole month's daily weather data (historical and forecast min max)

Comment: @Roman Thank you! I was able to use selenium in loading and examining another page in the website. I now know how to handle pages with dynamic content from your suggestion and the explanation below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you disable javascript in your browser you will find that none of the information you require is there. This is what Roman is explaining about. Javascript can make HTTP requests and grab data from APIs, the response is then fed back to the browser.

If you inspect the page and go to network tools. You will be able to see all the requests to load the page up. In those requests, there's one that if you click and go to preview, you'll see there's some temperature data.

[image]

I'm lazy so I copy the cURL of this request and input into a website like curl.trillworks.com which converts this to a python request.

[image]

Here you can see I'm copying the cURL request here.

### Code Example

```
import requests

params = (
    ('apiKey', '6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e'),
    ('geocode', '52.45,-1.75'),
    ('language', 'en-US'),
    ('units', 'e'),
    ('format', 'json'),
)

response = requests.get('https://api.weather.com/v3/wx/forecast/daily/15day', params=params)
max = response.json()['temperatureMax'][0]
min = response.json()['temperatureMin'][0]
print('Min Temperature: ',min)
print('Max Temperature: ',max)
```

### Output

```
Min Temperature: 65
Max Temperature: 87
```

### Explanation

So the url is an API that weather.com has for daily forecasts. It has parameters specifying where you are, the format the response should return.

We make an HTTP get request with those parameters and the response we get back is a JSON object. We can convert this to a python dictionary using `response.json()` method.

Now if you output response.json() you'll get a lot of data, if you look at the preview in your browser of that HTTP request you can have a navigate down to the data you want. We want the data in the keys 'temperatureMax' and 'temperatureMin'. The result actually a list, and todays temperature max and min are the first item of those lists. Hence `response.json()['temperatureMax'][0]` and `min = response.json()['temperatureMin'][0]`

### Additional Information

This is a case of the website has dynamic content which is loaded by javascript. There are two broad ways to deal with this type of content.

1. Mimic the HTTP request that the javascript invokes (This is what we have done here)
2. Use a package like selenium to invoke browser activity. You can use selenium to render the entire HTML including the javascript invoked parts of that HTML. Then select the data you want.

The benefit of the first option is efficency, it's much faster, the data is more structured. The reason to consider the last type of work last option is selenium was never meant for web scraping, it's brittle, if anything changes on the website then you'll find yourself in a position where you'll need to maintain the code often.

So my advice is try to do the first option, inspect the page, go to network tools and look at the previews of all the requests made. Play about with the previews data to see if it has what you want. Then re-create that request. Now sometimes you just need a simple HTTP request without parameters, cookies or headers.

In this particular example, you justed parameters, but sometimes you'll need all through and possibly more for different websites. So be mindful of that if you're not able to get the data. It's not fool proof, there are definitely instances that re-creating the HTTP request is difficult and there are things you as the user of the website are not privvy to which are required. Infact a well developed API which have this feature in to stop people scraping it.

Comment: thank you so much. this is a really clear answer to my confusion about dynamically-loaded websites and how to pinpoint which link/request in the network tab handles a specific content in the page

Comment: I was able to create a script which collects the temperature data (from the 15day forecast) and output it in dataframe/excel. however, I encountered a problem when I try to re-run the code again - somehow, the today's temperature (first entry in the array) became null when I checked the api in the network preview and so I am also getting a 'None' value when I try to scrape it. The scraping worked perfectly fine hours ago so I didn't understand why it now returns null. Can you shed some light here? (I'm editing my question to add the screenshot from the site)

Comment: Not too sure, I've had a look and getting the same output. It's more likely a problem at their end than your code. The other days forecast looks accurate.